# How to create dependent dropdown list side by side with an add option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add 2 dropdowns list side by side. Like first dropdown for skills like HTML5,CSS3,JS,PHP etc and 2nd dropdown for levels like begineer,advanced,expert etc. I also want to have an add button so i can keep on adding more skills. Below code helps me to add 2 buttons but vertically instead of aide by side. But I want to know how to have an add button.

```
<label for="skills">Skills</label>
<div id="example1" class="bs-docs-example">
<select class="step1">
<option value="">Please select an option</option>
<option>Option1</option>
<option>Option2</option>
<option>Option3</option>
<option>Option4</option>
</select>
</div>

<label for="skills">Level</label>
<div id="example2" class="bs-docs-example1">
<select class="step2">
<option value="">option</option>
<option>Option5</option>
<option>Option6</option>
<option>Option7</option>
<option>Option8</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: For populating options in second dropdown based on first, following is the [reference](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/817Ladnn/). Also kindly explain your question in more detail. Its little confusing.

Comment: regarding the "add" button: should the added skills be saved on the server? because if they should then you would need some serverside-language like for example PHP, ASP or JSP.

Comment: Thank you Rajesh. I want 2 dropdowns side by side. one for skills and another for level. Skills dropdowns will have C,C++,Java etc and Level dropdown will have begineer,expert,advanced etc. I want an add button to  add another skill in next line. Like i have a skill C with level of expert and also skill Java with level of begineer. so an add button will work here. hope you got it.

Comment: Hey low_rents. I also want them to be saved on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this then...

```js
$( "#add" ).click(function() {
   var row = $("#wrapper-1").clone();
    //row.remove("#add");
  $('#wrapper').append(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" width="100%">
    <div id="wrapper-1" style="float: left; width: 85%;">
    <div id="first" style="float: left; width: 65%;"> 
        <label for="skills">Skills</label>
        <select id="one" class="step1">
            <option value="">Please select an option</option>
            <option>Option1</option>
            <option>Option2</option>
            <option>Option3</option>
            <option>Option4</option>
         </select>
    </div>
    <div class="general" style="float: left; width: 35%;"> 
        <label for="skills">Level</label>
        <select class="step2">
            <option value="">option</option>
            <option>Option5</option>
            <option>Option6</option>
            <option>Option7</option>
            <option>Option8</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class="add-general" style="float: left; width: 15%;">
        <button id="add"> add </button>
    </div>  
 </div>
```

Comment: Hey nikki. I am finding a strange problem. Whenever I am clicking on add button its landing me on a different page and displays add successfully message. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Can you share your code here ? As there is no redirection code in the above  "Add" button click fuction.

Comment: I am afraid if I can paste it as its too long. Actually I have a form list created and when entered details, it will land me to a desired page. For this I have register button. But I do not know how this ADD button doing the same function. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry. But I can't suggest you anything without digging into your code. However, you can check if "Add" button's id or class matches with the register button's properties. Or debug it using browser debugger.

Comment: <div align="center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "register" />
   </div>
   </div>
   </form>....This is the code for the register button and for add button I have added the same code what you wrote down.

Comment: Can you share the redirect function that is being called when you click "Add" or "Register" button?

Comment: <form id='hire' method="post" action="jobseeker.php">
......<input class="btn btn-primary" type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "register" />
          </div>
          </form>

Comment: <?php
        {
          $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'skill')

or die('Error in Conection');

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];

$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

$companyname = $_POST['companyname'];

$emailid = $_POST['emailid'];

$password = $_POST['password'];


$query = "INSERT INTO jobseeker (fname, lname, companyname, emailid, password) values ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$companyname', '$emailid', '$password');";
   
mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die('Error in Connection');

echo 'Added Succesfully!';

mysqli_close($dbc);

  ?>

Comment: Hey nikki...I have added code here.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705927/instead-of-adding-another-element-it-is-landing-to-a-another-page

Answer (score 0):

add button will add "abc" option in skills select box.

```js
$( "#add" ).click(function() {
  $('#one').append( new Option("abc","abc") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 70%; float: left;" id="example1"class="bsdocs-example"> 
        <label for="skills">Skills</label>
        <select id="one" class="step1">
            <option value="">Please select an option</option>
            <option>Option1</option>
            <option>Option2</option>
            <option>Option3</option>
            <option>Option4</option>
         </select>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 30%" id="example2"> 
        <label for="skills">Level</label>
        <select class="step2">
            <option value="">option</option>
            <option>Option5</option>
            <option>Option6</option>
            <option>Option7</option>
            <option>Option8</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:100px" id="example2">
        <button id="add"> add </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Nikki. But I want add button to be on the same line. Also it should add a skill and level option in next line instead of above function. For example when you are adding list of experiences in a career page you can have a multiple experiences and an add button will help to add those multiple experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Try This... I hope this is your expected result :)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="skills">Skills</label></td>
        <td colspan="2">
        <select id="one" class="step1">
            <option value="">Please select an option</option>
            <option>Option1</option>
            <option>Option2</option>
            <option>Option3</option>
            <option>Option4</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><label for="skills">Level</label></td>
        <td colspan="2">
        <select id="two" class="step2">
            <option value="">option</option>
            <option>Option5</option>
            <option>Option6</option>
            <option>Option7</option>
            <option>Option8</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><button onclick="addSkill()"> add skill </button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<label id="currentSkills"></label>
```

javascript

```
function addSkill(){
    var newSkill=$('#one').val();
    var newLevel=$('#two').val();
    console.log(newSkill);
    $('#currentSkills').append(newSkill+'-'+newLevel+"<br>");
}
```

Comment: Looks perfect but add button not working. Thanks anyways